# Laravel: I want to display categories that only have data

Tags: laravel

I have products with categories. What I want is to display a list of categories that only have data products. This is the current picture:

> [image: Blockquote]

This is my database relations:

> [image: Blockquote]

This is my blade:

```
@foreach ($gmcategories as $gmc)
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-muted" aria-current="page" href="{{url('goldmart/'.$gmc->slug)}}">{{$gmc->category_name}}</a>
</li>
@endforeach
```

This is my controller:

```
public function readCategory($slug)
{
    $category = Gmcategories::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    $gmcategories = Gmcategories::all();
    if($gmcategories)
    {
        $gmproducts = Gmproducts::where('category_id', $category->id)->paginate(20);
        return view('frontend.pages.goldmart', compact('gmproducts', 'category', 'gmcategories'));
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

The point is categories that have no data does not display. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at `whereHas()`in the laraval documentation.

Comment: I've seen it but I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$customers = Gmcategories::withCount('gmproducts')
    ->having('gmproducts_count', '>', 0)
    ->get();
```

Comment: I tried it, but doesn't work!